# How to split a dataframe according to a column with duplicated rows

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have the following dataframe:

> data.frame(type = c("cell", "cell", "protein", "protein"),
> value = c(1,5,3,8))

I would like to split this dataframe into 2 different dataframes so as to have in each a unique value for the type column, like the following example:

```
type      value
cell       1
protein    3





  type      value
    cell       5
    protein    8
```

How can I do this in R? Thank you!